# Creating an array in C# that contains an object

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a `RequestModel` that contains some properties and another class `Consignment`.

Calling `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);` returns

```
{ "consignment": { "collectionDetails": null } }
```

Instead I would like to return an array of the object

```
"consignment": [ { "collectionDetails": null } ]
```

I've tried to create Consignment[] but get a conversion issue.

I've also tried to create a `List<Consignment>`

```
class RequestModel
{
    public string job_id { get; set; }
    public Consignment consignment = new Consignment();

    public class Consignment
    {
        public string consignmentNumber { get; set;
    }

    public string ToJSON()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
```

Comment: Where does `collectionDetails` come from? all i see is `consignmentNumber`. Also, why does job_id not show up, are you sure you are reading the correct json?

Comment: _"I've tried to create Consignment[] but get a conversion issue."_ perhaps show that code so we can help fix it

Comment: If you are using a List say called computerList of object Computer you need to use  List<Computer> computerList = new List<Computer>(); and then add as so                         computerList.Add(new Computer(words[0], words[1], "N/a", words[2], words[3]));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public string job_id { get; set; }
    public Consignment consignment { get; set; }

    public RequestModel()
    {
        consignment = new Consignment();
    }                

    public string ToJSON()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

Then your Consignment DTO would look like this assuming you have a `CollectionItems` class (didn't see any code in question around this):

```
public class Consignment
{
    public List<CollectionItems> collectionDetails { get; set; }
    public Consignment()
    {
        collectionDetails = new List<Collection>();
    }
}
```

Comment: many thanks this would work great! I realised I could do it outside of the Consignment class too.